Error when deploying to zkLink Nova using foundry-zksync
I am trying to deploy a contract to zkLink Nova using foundry-zksync. I am encountering the following error:
forge script script/Deploy.s.sol --rpc-url $RPC_URL --broadcast --zksync
server returned an error response: error code 3: Failed to serialize transaction: gas per pub data limit is zero

I've added the following lines to foundry.toml in order to support zksolc compilation:
[profile.default.zksync]
compile = true

Anyone has any idea on what is wrong here? The deployment works fine on other non zk networks

The scripts don’t work well in case of foundry-zksync due to the lack of support of some vm cheatcodes and all. You can deploy using the forge create command though.

Yep. As of today, forge scripting is very limited with ZKSync. At the moment, you should use bash scripting with forge create to deploy smart contracts.
